# Regex | Find content between 2 dynamic strings

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

I am currently working on a gulp plugin that finds syntax like `[! @if (this) !]` and `[! @endif !]` however, this is dynamic and the if can always change.

I want to be able to do some regex that I will be able to search a contents of a file for the if statement and get the contents that is in the middle so that I can choose whether or not to remove the content based on the flag that is passed with the command e.g `gulp --statements false` would not allow the statements to show no matter what is actually within them as that doesn't matter for development purposes.

So I could have code like this...

```
This is just some dummy data that will not get removed.

[! @if (this_is_some_var) !]
   I would be able to get this text!
[! @endif !]

This is some more dummy data that will not get removed.

[! @if (this_is_another_var) !]
    And this text!
[! @endif !]
```

So essentially I want the Javascript/RegEx to be able to return the following `I would be able to get this text!` and then with Javascript remove or keep that content depending on the argument that is passed in.

Comment: Perhaps this regex could be of help to you :)
`\[! @if \((?<var>\w+)\) !\]\s?(?<content>(?s:.+))\[! @endif !\]`

https://regex101.com/r/QGocEE/3

Answer (score 0):

This might be a starting point you could use.

```
\[\!(?!\!\]).+\!\]\s((?!\[\!).+)\s\[\!(?!\!\]).+\!\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/kz6K6i/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one

`/(?:^\[!\s@if\s\(.*\)\s!\])\s+(.*)\s+(?:\[!\s@endif\s!\]$)/gium;`

[demo](https://codepen.io/josejbreijo/pen/vRZmVy?editors=0012) & [regex playground](https://regexr.com/3mnmu)

Answer (score 0):

This may work for your case

```
\[! @if \((.*)\) !\]\s+(.*)(?=\s+\[! @endif !\])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/12)

- capture 1: each If-statement variable
- capture 2: content string to the If-statement